# Display `keys' of labels in TOC, listoffigures, list of tables, etc

Tags: table-of-contents

In editing a large document where individual editors work on chapters, some of the team regularly need to refer to `labels`/`keys` in other chapters.

User jfbu put together a nice solution... the code down the page.  Since the situation is always a bit involved for large multi-chapter multi-editor documents, the mwe is a bit involved too.  I have posted one in mwekeys.zip file: http://hep.ucsb.edu/mwe/ .  Three pages (TOC, lof, and lot) output showing the keys are displayed below.

There is still one flaw... when used with the package `chapterbib`, there is a hang at the end 
     `(./mwekeys.aux (./ONE.aux) (./TWO.aux))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
 
\par 
l.101 \end{document}

? q`

This hang only happens with `chapterbib`.

[image: TOC]
[image: lof]
[image: lot]

Comment: Do you mean a list of labels? The package `showkeys` can show the label inplace, i.e. where they are they defined

Comment: I was hoping for all of them in a centralized location, the easiest being just before or after the `short caption' in the listoffigures or listoftables.  So an editor of Chapter X doesn't have to hunt and peck through Chapter Y to find a key.  Ideally even the keys in the TOC would be shown too.

Comment: Which keys in the ToC???? What do you mean by keys in the TOC

Comment: I think each Chapter, Section, etc has a key that you can put in the \ref command... like, `for a discussion of quantum wormholes, refer to Chapter~\ref{quantworm}.'  I suspect those keys are already internal to LaTeX... of course I could add a \label inside the various commands.

Comment: No, they aren't -- look into `book.cls` for example. You won't find automatic labels

Comment: OK, but I can add them myself by redefining the \chapter command.  Of course maybe the problem is the association of the key with the actual chapter, table, figure info that ends up in the TOC, listoftables, listoffigures.

Comment: The file `ONE.tex` in your `zip` archive has errors due to use of `\ge` in the tabular, outside of math mode. Apart from that, seems to compile now with the code as posted in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**last update:** the hacky code below relies the `aux` file not containing at its very end a `\@writefile` line (when concerned with `lot`, `lof`, `toc`). Thus, one needs some means to put for example a `\relax` at the very end of the `.aux` file.

I achieve this with the help of package [atveryend](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend), and this modification appears robust enough for the sample files as provided by the OP.

I remove the very first version of the code, leaving only the one with the two added modifications (the one described here and the one with `\KOMAoptions` below).

---

**penultimate update:** adds also `lof` and `lot` to the entities handled by the hack. Appears to work. See code at bottom of answer.

---

**Update** as clarified in comments, the OP uses the `scrbook` document class. The code below was originally tested with  `article` class which has no `chapter`'s. The `\chapter` command by default (whether for `book` or `scrbook`) issues orders to add vertical spacings in List of Figures and List of Tables. These orders end up in the `.aux` file (or files) and my macro below does not see the `\newlabel` it is looking for.

1. Under `KOMA`'s `scrbook`, the following work-around is available. Add:

   ```
   \KOMAoptions{listof=nochaptergap}
   ```

   to the preamble.
2. If with the standard `book` class, then the simplest would be to patch (conditionally on the boolean `\ifHNNdraft`) the kernel macro `\@chapter`, removing from it `\addtocontents {lof}{\protect \addvspace {10\p@ }}\addtocontents {lot}{\protect \addvspace {10\p@ }}`. As surely many packages patch the `\chapter/\@chapter` commands, this might prove somewhat fragile, I thus don't discuss that any further. The `KOMA` allows much simpler solution given above. The macro below does not cause errors, but it is simply ineffective with labels following `\chapter`. It works correctly for `\part`'s and `\section`'s.

*remark* from past experience I knew that `biblatex` has a very stubborn tendency to add commands in-between lines of the `.toc` file, and I was thus suspicious this could endanger the hack here. Fortunately, at the level of the `aux` file, this is done before the `\@writefile` lines whose behavior is patched here, thus my macro does find the `\newlabel` next in the `.aux` file, and there is perhaps compatibility with `biblatex`(at least my single test).

Final remark: the code below has been tested with `hyperref` and is compatible.

---

*obsolete*: Here is a hack, which I haven't tested at all (you did not provide a mwe I could copy paste). Perhaps it will break at the first opportunity. But gives the idea.

---

The original code has been removed. This is the final code which uses [atveryend](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) package and `\KOMAoptions` command to address various issues.

```
\documentclass {scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}% for testing compatibility
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{chapterbib}% for testing compatibility

\usepackage{mwe}

% to put something at very end of main aux file
\usepackage{atveryend}% also loaded by hyperref
\makeatletter
    \AfterLastShipout{\immediate\write\@mainaux{\relax}}%
\makeatother

% boolean to activate or not insertion of label keys in toc, lof, lot:
\newif\ifHNNdraft
\HNNdrafttrue
% suppress key insertions in toc, lof, lot:
% \HNNdraftfalse

\makeatletter

\let\original@writefile\@writefile

\def\@writefile #1#2#3{\def\HNN@fileext{#1}%
     \let\HNN@next\original@writefile
     \in@{#1}{toc,lof,lot}%
     \ifin@
       \ifx\newlabel#3%
          \def\HNN@next ##1##2\newlabel
         {\futurelet\HNN@tmp\HNN@writefile #2\empty\HNN@writefile}%
       \fi
     \fi
     \HNN@next {#1}{#2}#3% fingers extra crossed
}%
\def\HNN@writefile 
{%
    \ifx\HNN@tmp\contentsline\expandafter\HNN@writefile@a\else
                             \expandafter\HNN@writefile@abort
    \fi
}%
\def\HNN@writefile@a \contentsline #1#2#3\HNN@writefile #4%
{%
    \original@writefile{\HNN@fileext}{\contentsline{#1}{#2\HNN@showkey {#4}}#3}%
    \newlabel {#4}%
}%
\def\HNN@writefile@abort #1\HNN@writefile
{%
    \original@writefile{\HNN@fileext}{#1}\newlabel
}%
\protected\def\HNN@showkey #1%
         {\ifHNNdraft\space\space \textit{key:} \texttt{#1}\fi}

\ifHNNdraft
   \KOMAoptions{listof=nochaptergap}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\thispagestyle{empty}

\part{PART WITH LABEL}\label{hello}

\chapter{CHAPONE}\label{chap1}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{FIRST MWE to demonstrate how to place to images side-by-side}
\label{fig:BU}
\end{figure}

\section{foo}\label{foo}

Let me check \autoref{bar}.
Let me check \autoref{bob}.

\section{bar}\label{bar}

Let me check \autoref{foo}.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{SECOND MWE to demonstrate how to place to images side-by-side}
\label{fig:JF}
\end{figure}

\section{with no label}
\subsection{with no label}

\part{PART WITHOUT LABEL}

\chapter{CHAPONE OF PART TWO}\label{chapII1}
\section{without label}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    mountain&sea&lake
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sample table}\label{JF}
\end{table}
\section{bob}\label{bob}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    apple&banana&strawberry
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sample table II}\label{BU}
\end{table}
\section{bib}
Let me check \autoref{foo}.

\end{document}
```

The image below illustrate the initially posted test file. Result with above code is similar, with keys also in `LOT` and `LOF`.

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: sections `foo`, `bar`, `bob` have labels of the same name by sheer laziness. The `part` example with label `hello` shows the macro is really picking up the label. Other remark: I always put `\label` externally to `\section` argument, and the macro assumes that.

Comment: I implemented your code in a simple scrbook condiment (from KOMA-script).  Works fine.  But there is an aspect that breaks it... I use this snippet to read in a chapter from a lower directory:     \newcommand{\ChapLabel}{chap:empty}
\newcommand{\tdrinclude}[1]
{
%\befchap
\renewcommand{\ChapLabel}{chap:#1} % define the label for the chapter
\subincludefrom{#1/}{#1}
%\aftchap
}    So, for a directory/chapter named ONE, if I put \label{\ChapLabel} next to the \chapter{} command, I'm able to successfully use either ref{\ChapLable} or \ref{chap:ONE}.  But I don't see chap:ONE in the key

Comment: possibly a problem of multiple `.aux` files. I don't know how `\subincludefrom` works. Without an explicit `mwe`, hard to provide anything concrete.

Comment: I've not found it easy to post files/formats outside of the primary post... it does look like the TeX to put the key for the chapter is ending up in ONE.aux, and not in mwekeys.aux, in the mwe I have posted at http://hep.ucsb.edu/mwe/ .  \subincludefrom is from the import package. thanks.

Comment: I tried changing from \subincludefrom to \subimport, and the multiple .aux files disappear.  The label/key combination for the chapter is declared in the single .aux file, but for Chapter One, somehow does not get into the .toc file.

Comment: ok, this is not a problem of multiple `.aux` file, but a problem of the behavior of `\chapter` command in `KOMA` classes. It wants to add extra vertical spacing  in the `list of figures` and `list of tables` files, this intent ends up putting extra lines in the `aux` file, and my macro does not find the `\newlabel` it is looking for. I will think a bit if I see a way out. (you can check that labeling sections works, even in chapter TWO).

Comment: I see your point.  Not KOMA though, also vanilla book class has the same issue. thanks.

Comment: ah ok, this shows I am also not familiar with `book` class. Thanks, will correct my wording.

Comment: thx!  ..advice... parallel extension to the lof and the lot.... should I make a new question from scratch?  feel I'm wearing out welcome, but also, this is extremely useful stuff for large document editors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30836/discussion-between-hnn-and-jfbu).

Comment: You can edit your original question adding a `mwe` (no need for complications with `import` package etc... for figures, there is package `mwe`). Also editing your question will let it be seen to other people. I will not be on internet for the next few days. Will spend a few minutes trying to anticipate you `lof`, `lot` concerns.

Comment: updated top post... still hanging at end, traced to chapter bib package

Comment: @HNN the problem is caused by `\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\relax}}` not doing what I naively expected, other things depending on circumstances get written afterwards to the `.aux` file, and possibly a `\@writefile` will be last. At this time I don't have time to research the issue, surely people here know to handle the question "How to put something at the very end of the aux file?". You should ask a new question. By the way, external links are not good for questions. You could and should have included into your question a sufficiently complete `mwe`,  no need to bother with secondary files

Comment: OK, so just the `main' file is sufficient for an mwe?

Comment: there is also an extra command (`\providecommand` below) in lot files that can cause an lot key to disappear:  \@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1.1.1}{\ignorespaces Chapters and Three Letter Codes\relax }}{2}{table.caption.2}}
\providecommand*\caption@xref[2]{\@setref\relax\@undefined{#1}}
\newlabel{ODt:codes}{{1.1.1}{2}{Chapters and Three Letter Codes\relax }{table.caption.2}{}}

Comment: So at least I'm able run smoothly if I go into \nonstopmode

Comment: I think that the problem is in `chapterbib.sty`, which writes into the `main.aux` file (not the Chap aux files) some lines like   \gdef\@extra@binfo{}\@writefile{toc}{\gdef \the@ipfilectr{}}\@writefile{lof}{\gdef \the@ipfilectr{}}\@writefile{lot}{\gdef \the@ipfilectr{}}.  In `chapterbib.sty`, \def\@CB@writeContext{\if@filesw\begingroup
  \edef\@tempa{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@extra@b@citeb}}%
from \immediate\write\@auxout{\@tempa\@CB@wtoc{toc}\@CB@wtoc{lof}\@CB@wtoc{lot}}%
  \endgroup\fi}
\def\@CB@wtoc#1{\string\@writefile{#1}{\gdef
  \string\the@ipfilectr{\@extra@b@citeb}}}%

Comment: somehow your hack breaks this output.

Comment: `chapterbib.sty`  writes a line about `toc, lof, and lot` into the `main.aux` file twice each time `include` is used.  Somehow the last of these writes, which always concerns `lot`, is what your hack breaks.  Must somehow be in the `\@writefile` you redefine.

Comment: put a much simplified `mwe` at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275929/early-file-end-due-to-chapterbib-and-keylist

Comment: tested new solution, it works

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?
This hooks into `\label` and adds a `toc` entry to `.lab` ToC and provides a `list of labels` command.

It will probably not work with `cleveref` (at the moment)

Short note: It does not take the `draft` option so far.

```
\documentclass{book}




\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listoflabels}{%
  \section*{List of labels}
  \@starttoc{lab}
}
\makeatother



\usepackage{xpatch}

\xapptocmd{\label}{\addcontentsline{lab}{section}{\texttt{#1}}}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\listoflabels

\chapter{First}\label{firstchapter}

\section{First}\label{first}


\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{firstequation}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Using a `labels` documentclass option:

```
\documentclass[labels]{book}

\newif\iflabeloptionused

\DeclareOption{labels}{\labeloptionusedtrue}
\ProcessOptions*



\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listoflabels}{%
  \iflabeloptionused
  \section*{List of labels}
  \@starttoc{lab}
  \fi
}
\makeatother



\usepackage{xpatch}

\xapptocmd{\label}{\addcontentsline{lab}{section}{\texttt{#1}}}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\listoflabels

\chapter{First}\label{firstchapter}

\section{First}\label{first}

\blindtext[15]
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{firstequation}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to just get the keys to be right there in each line of the TOC, or list of figures/tables... that way the info like chapter/section & short captions would be easily correlated with the keys.

Comment: @HNN: You demand a lot of things for not providing a MWE or a clear question ;-) If you would have made it clearer right from the start I could have saved some time -- not wasting time on this solution :-(

Comment: Sorry, I posted some images that depict what I hope for.