# How to put something at the very end of the aux file?... Hang at the end with chapterbib

Tags: auxiliary-files

Pretty clear that the hack breaks `chapterbib.sty`'s output concerning `toc, lof, and lot` info into the `main.aux` (in the case below, `main=mwekeys`) file, performed even if `\tableofcontents`, `\listofigures`, and `\listoftables` are all absent; these writes into the `main.aux` are trigger by `chapterbib.sty`'s altered `include` command.

I'm coordinating a multi-editor report, and use the `chapterbib` package to output chapter-level bibliographies.   User jfbu has kindly helped me output the `keys` to the TOC, lof, and lot, which is enormously helpful to cross-chapter editing jobs.  ([Display `keys' of labels in TOC, listoffigures, list of tables, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275250/display-keys-of-labels-in-toc-listoffigures-list-of-tables-etc/275295?noredirect=1#comment663450_275295)).  When `chapterbib` is used, the compilation hangs at the end (how below).

Anyone know how to cure this?

```
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 101.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 101.
(./mwekeys.aux (./ONE.aux) (./TWO.aux))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.101 \end{document}

 q
OK, entering \batchmode...
```

here is the main file/mwe:

```
% basic page setup
\documentclass[oneside,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twocolumn=false}
\KOMAoptions{paper=letter}
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=true}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearplainofpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Testing Keys}
\cfoot[]{\rule{0pt}{2ex}\pagemark}
\ifoot[]{}
\ofoot[]{}

% packages... sorry so many
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[numbers,square,comma,sort&compress,merge]{natbib}  % For endnotes
\usepackage{chapterbib}

% get Chapter labels and bibliography label automatically

\newcommand{\ChapLabel}{chap:empty}
\newcommand{\BibLabel}{emptyS:bib}
\newcommand{\tdrinclude}[1]
{
%\befchap
 \renewcommand{\ChapLabel}{chap:#1} % define the label for the chapter
 \renewcommand{\BibLabel}{#1S:bib} % define the label for the chapter
 \subincludefrom{#1/}{#1}
  %\aftchap
}

\newcommand{\tdrchap}[1]
{
  \chapter{#1}\label{\ChapLabel}
}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{Bibliography}\label{\BibLabel}}

%\numberwithin{figure}{section}
%\numberwithin{table}{section}
%\numberwithin{equation}{section}


% The key display code

\newif\ifHNNdraft
\HNNdrafttrue

\makeatletter

\let\original@writefile\@writefile

\def\@writefile #1#2#3{\def\HNN@fileext{#1}%
     \let\HNN@next\original@writefile
     \in@{#1}{toc,lof,lot}%
     \ifin@
       \ifx\newlabel#3%
          \def\HNN@next ##1##2\newlabel
         {\futurelet\HNN@tmp\HNN@writefile #2\empty\HNN@writefile}%
       \fi
     \fi
     \HNN@next {#1}{#2}#3% fingers extra crossed
}%
\def\HNN@writefile 
{%
    \ifx\HNN@tmp\contentsline\expandafter\HNN@writefile@a\else
                             \expandafter\HNN@writefile@abort
    \fi
}%
\def\HNN@writefile@a \contentsline #1#2#3\HNN@writefile #4%
{%
    \original@writefile{\HNN@fileext}{\contentsline{#1}{#2\HNN@showkey {#4}}#3}%
    \newlabel {#4}%
}%
\def\HNN@writefile@abort #1\HNN@writefile
{%
    \original@writefile{\HNN@fileext}{#1}\newlabel
}%
\protected\def\HNN@showkey #1%
         {\ifHNNdraft\space\space \textit{key:} \texttt{#1}\fi}

\ifHNNdraft
   \AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout {\relax}}% important
   \KOMAoptions{listof=nochaptergap}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
\tdrinclude{ONE}
\tdrinclude{TWO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: running in \nonstopmode at least lets me run smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "put something at the very end of the aux file", the following may be tried:

```
\usepackage{atveryend}% also loaded by hyperref
\makeatletter
    \AfterLastShipout{\immediate\write\@mainaux{\relax}}%
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atveryend}% also loaded by hyperref
\let\WHATEVER\relax
\makeatletter
    \AfterLastShipout{\immediate\write\@mainaux{\relax\WHATEVER}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}\label{sec:1}

\subsection{Bar}\label{sec:2}
\end{document}
```

Contents of `aux` file:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Foo}{1}}
\newlabel{sec:1}{{1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Bar}{1}}
\newlabel{sec:2}{{1.1}{1}}
\relax \WHATEVER
```